# Zoom H1n recorder not recognised by Windows 10. Only charges the device

Tags: windows-10, usb, audio

For the past few months, whenever I connected my H1n to my laptop (no battery cells or sd card inserted in H1n), a USB screen used to pop up asking if I wanted to record via SD Card or via my laptop.

Today, I was playing with FL Studio and I chose to record audio via that application. And suddenly, I got an error message "Last USB device connected malfunctioned".

Since then, I don't get the USB Screen to select where I want to record audio. 
I used to record audio in audacity earlier, and it worked best. Now, my laptop nor my friend's laptop recognise H1n. I tried factory resetting but it didn't help. Now, it only starts up / powers on when we connect it to the laptop. It doesn't allow us to record audio in the laptop.

I use windows 10.

Please help me.

Comment: Replace the USB cable.

Comment: I have tried that too. Different cables, different laptops. No difference.

Comment: Not all cables are equal, some don't allow data transfer.

Comment: Yes, I tried the ones which allow data transfer.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little late, but this is what worked for me:

1. My Zoom H1N worked ok as an interface. One day it stopped: connected with the same USB cable, when starting it was initializing "standalone recorder"  mode, as if not connected at all.
2. I turned off the Zoom and pulled the cable out from my computer
3. I went to Control Panel > Device manager. The USB controllers list was opened and one USB device was in error, with a yellow warning sign
4. I deleted the device altogether from the list (Windows will re-install a device when needed)
5. I plugged the cable back, turned the Zoom on
6. It initialized properly with connection questions

Hope it helps.